# UIRefreshControl crashes on Xamarin iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin, xamarin.ios

This should not be a problem at all, looking at all the answers out there on Stackoverflow, but I just can't find out how to do this with a UITableView (**not a TableViewController**). I use the following code

```
 if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(6, 0))
 {
    _refreshControl = new UIRefreshControl();
    _refreshControl.ValueChanged += OnRefreshRequested;
    ResultsTableView.RefreshControl = _refreshControl;
 }
```

and noticed that there's a warning saying that the line

```
ResultsTableView.RefreshControl = _refreshControl;
```

Is only available in API 10 and above? I thought this might be one of Xamarin Studios many quirks, but saw that it actually does crash on any OS version less than 10. With exception

```
NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableView setRefreshControl:]: 
unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15f420c00'
```

I would just like some help on how I can add a refresh control too my UITableView in OS versions lower than 10.

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hopefully this will help out anyone who is still trying to figure this out.  I had to declare the following at the top of my ViewController

```
UIRefreshControl refreshControl;
```

Then I did the following where I was trying to set up the refresh control:

```
refreshControl = new UIRefreshControl(); 
refreshControl.AddTarget((sender, args) => GetData(), UIControlEvent.ValueChanged); 

if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(10, 0)) 
{ 
    TableView.RefreshControl = refreshControl; 
} else { 
    TableView.AddSubview(refreshControl); 
}
```

Then instead of referencing the `RefreshControl` on `TableView` I just have to reference `refreshControl`

Comment: you're a life saver

Answer (score -1):

[Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uirefreshcontrol):

> Because the refresh control is specifically designed for use in a table view that's managed by a table view controller, using it in a different context can result in undefined behavior.
>
> SDK iOS 6.0+

Comment: Thanks you for taking time to find that. I'm hoping someone has a workaround for it. I'm implementing my own basic refresh logic and ui for now.